# Laravel - Model created by custom query

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to laravel, and I have no idea how to search for this.

I do have the following structure:

```
table_a -> a_id, name, document;

table_b -> b_id, a_id, sys_id, com_id, deleted_at;
```

Mainly `table_a` will store the data of a "user" and `table_b` contains the relation of system/companys that have acces to the data published to that user.

I will always need the data like: `a_id, name, document, []int sys, []int com;`

To do so I would like to create a model that is "populated"  with the following query:

```
select a.a_id, a.name, a.document, ARRAY_AGG(distinct(b.sys_id)) sys, ARRAY_AGG(b.com_id) com
from table_a a 
left join table_b b on a.a_id = b.a_id
     and b.deleted_at is null
group by 1,2,3
```

in a way that i can do:
`model->all()` and `model->where("document", 111)`

Obs:  I tried to do so using one to many relation, but i want to get the data in a single object.

Obs2:  I thought about creating a custom class with distinct "constructors" in a way that one returns an array of it and the other one returns an object.

Comment: "I tried to do so using one to many relation, but i want to get the data in a single object." - you mean from a single property/method?

Comment: You might searching for "[Global Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#anonymous-global-scopes)"

Comment: @Gui I'm mainly a go dev, i'm not familirized with the PHP semantics. 
What I want to achieve is something like: 
$var  = customModel::firstOrFail()
and be able to: 
dump($var->sys)  to get an array. 
I would prefer it as a property that is inicialized with the class. This info is essential to the usage of the model and I would like to avoid useless querys every time i need this info.

Comment: Why don't you create Models (Users, Companies) to store data ? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions

Comment: I think you need to do some reading to understand how Laravel and, more generally, model-view-controller frameworks operate. A model is an object representation of a database table; it is related to other models via foreign keys. A model, therefore, does not contain information from multiple tables at once. But access to properties of a related model is certainly as simple as `$model->relationship->property`.

Comment: @Gui  The "global scopes" was what I was looking for. 
Thanks.

Comment: @miken32  I do understand that.
Probably the "right" way of doing this is to create a class / hellper that would use both models to bring the right data.

That said using relations in the "right way" would do tons of extra querys and useless computation that could easily be retrived using a single query.

Comment: Eager loading a relationship results in a single extra query, and it's using an indexed foreign key so it's generally very fast.

Comment: As mentioned before I'm not used to Laravel and i'm probably wrong here (asking for learning).
If I use that I think that I would need to loop through the relations to get an array of company_ids and sys_ids (I need that info to publish on a queue).
I may be wrong but i was taught that if I can avoid a loop after querying data I'm suposed to do that.  
If you don't mind sharing how you would do that i will appreciate. 
Btw, Thx for repying i'm taking note of the tips. 
After re-reading your coments again i'm probably not suposed to be using a model here but instead a custom class.

Comment: It's far too broad to address in comments, especially with as little code as you've provided here. You just need to set up relationships between the models properly and then everything is done for you with little overhead. One of the main purposes of using Laravel is to avoid having to know about SQL syntax.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer: As mentioned by [miken32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70437194/laravel-model-created-by-custom-query#comment124514415_70437194) what I'm trying to do isn't the right way to use a model-view-controller framework as laravel.**

That said the solution for what I was looking for indeed are the global scopes [as suggested by Gui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70437194/laravel-model-created-by-custom-query#comment124511564_70437194)